# Scrape permalinks to answers posted under a certain question on Quora via Python-Selenium Web Driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am a beginner in Python-Selenium scraping. I want to scrape permalink of all the Quora answers posted under a question. So far I have created the following code snippet. But when I run it, it gives me only one link in the output. This is due to the fact that the page isn't loaded fully I guess. What should I do to get at least 100 permalinks to answers from the page source?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver_option.add_argument(" — incognito")
chromedriver_path = './chromedriver'
def create_webdriver():
 return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, chrome_options=driver_option)

f = open('file_text.txt', 'w')
# Open the website
browser = create_webdriver()
browser.get("https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory")

projects = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='answer_permalink']")

for proj in projects:
 anslink = proj.get_attribute('href')
 f.write(anslink)

f.close()
```

Comment: check my answer below, is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'answer_permalink'}):
    print(item.get("href"))
```

Output:

```
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Dave-Morgan-14
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Ken-Natco
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Matthew-Writer
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Chance-Thompson-13
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/27223260
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/26836797
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Frida-Schiess
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Pierre-Ripplinger
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jacob-Fu
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Mike-Howells-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Mick-Stute
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jesse-Bridges-III
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Renard-Leblanc
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/26831140
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/27158717
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Chris-Lockwood-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/David-Minger
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Rick-Brown-50
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jacques-Malan-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Robert-Lent-1
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/79419339
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Dave-Consiglio
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/65113366
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Krishnabh-Medhi
```

Selenium Approach:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get(
    'https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory')

lenOfPage = driver.execute_script(
    "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")

match = False
while(match == False):
    lastCount = lenOfPage
    lenOfPage = driver.execute_script(
        "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    if lastCount >= 51000:
        break

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
count = 0
for item in soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'answer_permalink'}):
    count += 1
    print(item.get("href"))
print(count)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Dave-Morgan-14
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Ken-Natco
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Matthew-Writer
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Chance-Thompson-13
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/27223260
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/26836797
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Frida-Schiess
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Pierre-Ripplinger
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jacob-Fu
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Mike-Howells-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Mick-Stute
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jesse-Bridges-III
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Renard-Leblanc
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/26831140
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Danya-Rose
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Chris-Lockwood-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/David-Minger
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Rick-Brown-50
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jacques-Malan-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Robert-Lent-1
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/John-Lind-22
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Dave-Consiglio
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/65113366
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Krishnabh-Medhi
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/44569062
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Abd-Ul-Rahman-Lomax
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Helmut-Walle
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Ed-Kohlwey-1
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jason-Ree-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Drew-Curry
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Darrel-Blakely-2
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Alexander-Kunz-2
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Michael-Greenberg-61
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Matthew-Schenker
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Gregory-Hart-8
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Mark-Giammattei
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Vernon-Bender
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Brett-Evill
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Kurt-Mager
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Michael-Brenner-13
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Luke-Anderson-87
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Sassa-Neuf
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Spandan-Mallick
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/58252346
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Timothy-Lamothe
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Eric-Schwertfeger
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/70843234
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Tony-Flury
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Aji-Jijo
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Tia-Eastlake
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Michael-Grace-53
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Ray-Mason-30
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jimmy-May-2
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Thomas-Edward-Samuel-Thomas
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Alan-Atkinson-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Joseph-Perkins-11
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/David-Ridlen
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Charles-Li-86
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/140610748
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Corentin-Oger
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jean-Pierre-Choisy
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Tom-Kubin
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/120618033
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Charles-Brenchley-1
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jonathan-Johnson-41
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Edward-Teach-53
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Tony-Price-50
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Nathaniel-Day-8
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Nuurussubchiy-Fikriy
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/150581075
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/87762707
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Neil-219
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Alex-Frantz-1
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Andy-P-Zbinden
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Uriel-Anderson-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Chris-OLeary-19
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Daniel-Gerber-7
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Roy-Wilson-64
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Randy-Wonsowicz-Jr
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Leslie-Harrington-4
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Eddie-Olsson
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Vincent-Emery
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Maxwell-Perry-3
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Matthew-Granovsky
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/83259600
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Benjamin-Dixon-17
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/John-Chambers-75
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Ryne-Hanz
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Eric-Rodriguez-137
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Robert-Hopkins-90
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Sasha-Maddah
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Owen-Lee-126
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/David-Phillips-133
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Hasan-Poonawala-1
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Cristiano-Dal-Vi
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Rex-Newborn
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/John-Neumann-9
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Josh-D-Davis
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Maruthi-Sreenath
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Clint-Morgan-2
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Nicholas-Volkmuth
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Richard-Swim
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/143504277
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Christer-Svanström
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Steve-Schlackman-2
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/147597845
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Rene-Dukundane-Felix
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/148753762
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Henk-Schuring
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/135814117
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Emilio-Trampuz
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/40529643
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Karl-Sangree
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Ted-Carriker
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/egi-syahban
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Mayank-Dahiya-12
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Robert-Jones-741
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Jimmi-Carlsson-1
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Cole-Johnson-24
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answer/Kram-Redarsh
/How-do-I-prove-the-flat-earth-theory/answers/64915389
```

Comment: Yes, its indeed working but wouldn't it be limited? Suppose there are 1000 answers, there then it will not work I guess. Btw thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @SulemanElahi you mean that you want the links which appears after you press on view more ?

Comment: @SulemanElahi that's completely different thing. actually according to your question, this is the links which in page source. other links only appears after you keep scrolling down !

Comment: Okay, then I think I proceed on my own.